# Automating report delivery via email to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We want to setup a delivery report from one of our platforms.So if I set the time there to generate and email report every night I want that file to be sent to a S3 bucket on AWS.

What I have done so far ?

I have use the SES service. I was not able to verify the domains. I am not sure if we can bypass this option or will our IT admin allow it.

I did verify the email address. I set up a bucket with policies mentioned here .
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-permissions.html

I was able to sent test mail via mail address send a test mail. When I checked the bucket I had a message which said

```
Hello,

You received this message because you attempted to set up Amazon SES to deliver emails to this S3 bucket.

Please note that the rule that you configured to deliver emails to this S3 bucket is only valid if the entire setup process is successful. For more information about
setting up email-receiving rules, see the Amazon SES Developer Guide at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html .

Thank you for using Amazon SES!

The Amazon SES Team
```

Do I have a workaround ? Thank you

Comment: This is too broad of a question. Answer is yes, it can be done. However devil is in the details.

Comment: Everynight on a platform we set a trigger to send a report to my mail address. I wanted to know if that could be sent to a s3 bucket where the file will be saved

Comment: If it's a file, it can be sent to S3. That's still too broad. If you want to know how, you need to add details of this setup, limitations etc, not mentioning prior research you've done.

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha I just modified my question.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you weren't able to verify your domain. This is first step in making SES-to-S3 scheme work, according to docs: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-receive-inbound-emails/

So you need to fix this problem and go through next step in the process.